# PyCharm import vs interpreter

Tags: python, import, pycharm

There is the following PyCharm project structure:

```
testImport
    target
        __init__.py
        script_1.py
        script_2.py
```

The contents are following:

```
#script_1.py
import datetime

now_ts = datetime.datetime.now()
```

```
#script_2.py
from script_1 import now_ts

print('Now: {}'.format(now_ts))
```

PyCharm requires me to correct the import line in the `script_2.py` file and use `from target.script_1 import now_ts`. Once I try to execute `~/testImport: ./target/script_2.py` I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'target'`. How is it possible that PyCharm suggests incorrect solution or is there something going on that I don't know about?

Comment: This might be part of the PEP-8 linter, since it's recommended to use [absolute imports](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) rather than relative imports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PyCharm suggestion is probably because the IDE consider that your `target` folder is a module. Having an executable script in a module is considered an anti pattern. [See Guido Van Rossum opinion about it](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2007-April/006793.html).

> I'm -1 on this and on any other proposed twiddlings of the **main**
> machinery. **The only use case seems to be running scripts that happen
> to be living inside a module's directory, which I've always seen as an
> antipattern**. To make me change my mind you'd have to convince me that
> it isn't.

I suggest that you change the structure of your project to make your main logic in a module, and the executable outside of the module, i.e:

```
testImport
├── script_1.py
└── target
    └── my_logic.py
```

And in your script_1.py :

```py
from target.my_logic import now_ts
```

**Note**: Of course, I am just using a call to authority as an argument here. With your use case, it might be better to continue the way you are developing. In that case, just dismiss the IDE suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The key point is that when your run your script in the default way `python ./target/script_2.py`, the interpreter considered `script_2` as **main** module and won't let you find upper folder.

You can run in the following ways to aviod `ModuleNotFoundError` (only if you clearly understand what you are doing, don't use in large project):

1. in `~/testImport` run `python -m target.script_2`
2. script_2.py add in the top

```py
__package__ = "target.script_2"
```

3. script_2.py add in the top

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    import os
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.curdir))
```

in `~/testImport` and run `python ./target/script_2.py`

I would be very appreciate if anyone could help me correct my unnatural english.